# Storing Listbox Value Generated by a Row Source Query

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to store the value of a listbox (Actual_Polygon_Area) that has been generated via row source query.  Each time I run the script my message box tells me that the value of the listbox is null and I suspect it's caused by the row source.  The suspected listbox is named Actual_Polygon_Area and the field I am trying to store it in is Polygon_Area within the table FS_Actual_Polygon.

```
Private Sub Actual_Polygon_Save_Click()

If IsNull(Actual_Polygon_Year) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a year in which this polygon received treatment"
    Actual_Polygon_Year.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Actual_Polygon_Season) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the season in which this polygon received treatment"
    Actual_Polygon_Season.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Actual_Polygon_Treatment) Then
    MsgBox "Please select the treatment type that was completed in this polygon."
    Actual_Polygon_Treatment.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Actual_Polygon_Notes) Then
    MsgBox "Please write a short summary regarding treatment goals and objectives."
    Actual_Polygon_Notes.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Actual_Polygon_Area) Then
    MsgBox "Polygon Area is null, please enter a value"
    Actual_Polygon_Area.SetFocus

Else

    Dim MyConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Set MyConnection = CurrentProject.Connection

    Dim rsFS_Actual_Polygon As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rsFS_Actual_Polygon = New ADODB.Recordset


    If IsNull(PolygonNo) Then
        'add
        rsFS_Actual_Polygon.Open "select * from FS_Actual_Polygon where PolygonNo= " & Actual_Polygon_ID & " and Treatment_Season= '" & Actual_Polygon_Season & "' and Treatment_Type= '" & Actual_Polygon_Treatment & "' and Project_Name = '" & Actual_Polygon_Project_Name & "' and Polygon_Area = " & Actual_Polygon_Area.Value & " and Treatment_Year = " & Actual_Polygon_Year, _
            MyConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    If Not rsFS_Actual_Polygon.EOF Then
        MsgBox "The combination of Polygon ID, treatment-year, treatment-season, and treatment type already exist.  Please check the combination."
        Actual_Polygon_Year.SetFocus
    Else
        With rsFS_Actual_Polygon
        .AddNew
            ![PolygonID] = Actual_Polygon_ID
            ![Project_Name] = Actual_Polygon_Project_Name
            ![Polygon_Area] = Actual_Polygon_Area.Value
            ![Treatment_Year] = Actual_Polygon_Year
            ![Treatment_Season] = Actual_Polygon_Season
            ![Treatment_Type] = Actual_Polygon_Treatment
            ![Polygon_Notes] = Actual_Polygon_Notes
        .Update
        End With

        Actual_Polygon_Record.Requery
        Actual_Polygon_New_Click
    End If
```

I can post the rest of the code if necessary, I just didn't want to post a huge chunk.

Comment: Does Actual_Polygon_Area have more than one column? If so, which column are you attempting to return?

Comment: @it has 3 columns but only the first column is the area I'm hoping to store in the table.

Comment: Try using `.Column(0)` instead of `.Value`. Not sure if that will fix it though. Is your listbox single or multi-select?

Comment: @ChristopherD. Switching to .Column(0) doesn't seem to be working either :/.  Any other ideas?  Also the list box is just set to the default, which should be single select I believe.  Do you know of any other cases where someone is trying to store a list box value that has been generated by a row source query?  I can't find anything, but it surely shouldn't be this hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.ItemsSelected` and `.ItemData` methods to find and pass the value of the selected row from the listbox to your table.

This is a fairly typical use of the listbox control, and is a little easier than dealing with a multi-select control, but is still a bit cumbersome. You will need to create a `For Each...Next` loop to collect the row number of the selected row in your listbox and save to a variable. Then use that variable as the argument of the `.ItemData` method to return the bound column value for that selected row.

This [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823015.aspx) article should have everything you need.

**EDIT:** While the above solution works for multi and single select listboxes, there is a more expedient way for single select listboxes:

```
Dim i as Integer
i = Me!Actual_Polygon_Area.ListIndex
If i = -1 Then
  MsgBox "No item has been selected"
  Exit Sub
End If
'Do above prior to `WITH` loop
...'Then in your `WITH` loop:
![Polygon_Area] = Actual_Polygon_Area.ItemData(i)
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for pointing me in that direction, I ended up getting it to work!  I appreciate your help!